# Customize pageable display in openapi

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm working on a spring boot project with OPENAPI as a tool for api documentation.

I have tried to override the display of the pageable json object in the UI with intuitive inputs (page - pageSize - sort)

```
   public OperationCustomizer parameterCustomizer() {
        return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {

            Parameter page = new Parameter()
                    .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                    .schema(new IntegerSchema()._default(0))
                    .name("page")
                    .description("La page (0..N)")
                    .required(true);
            Parameter size = new Parameter()
                    .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                    .schema(new IntegerSchema()._default(10))
                    .name("pageSize")
                    .description("Nombre de résultats par page")
                    .required(true);
            Parameter sort = new Parameter()
                    .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                    .schema(new ArraySchema())
                    .name("sort")
                    .description("Critère de tri avec le format: property(,asc|desc). "
                            + "Tri par défaut: ascendant. "
                            + "Multiple critères de tri sont supportés.");
            if(operation.)
            operation.addParametersItem(page);
            operation.addParametersItem(size);
            operation.addParametersItem(sort);
            return operation;
        };
    }
```

This is working but the parameters page , pageSize and sort are added to all methods
how can i make this works only for methods requiring pageable?

Answer (score 0):

find it ! i have to check in the handlerMethod if the pageable class exists within the parameter types:

```
    public OperationCustomizer parameterCustomizer() {
        return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {
            if (Arrays.asList(handlerMethod.getMethod().getParameterTypes()).contains(Pageable.class)) {
                Parameter page = new Parameter()
                        .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                        .schema(new IntegerSchema()._default(0))
                        .name("page")
                        .description("La page (0..N)")
                        .required(true);
                Parameter size = new Parameter()
                        .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                        .schema(new IntegerSchema()._default(10))
                        .name("pageSize")
                        .description("Nombre de résultats par page")
                        .required(true);
                Parameter sort = new Parameter()
                        .in(ParameterIn.QUERY.toString())
                        .schema(new ArraySchema())
                        .name("sort")
                        .description("Critère de tri avec le format: property(,asc|desc). "
                                + "Tri par défaut: ascendant. "
                                + "Multiple critères de tri sont supportés.");
                operation.addParametersItem(page);
                operation.addParametersItem(size);
                operation.addParametersItem(sort);
            }
            return operation;
        };
    }
```